# Keep Awake Not Actually Working

Tags: screen, android-11, developer-options, sleep

By enabling the *Stay Awake* toggle under *Developer Options*, which are enabled, my previous phone kept the display on when it was connected via USB. This no longer works on my current phone, which runs Android 11. *Developer Options* are enabled and the *Stay Away* toggle is on (Under it says: *Screen will never sleep while charging*) and my *Screen Saver* is also set to *Off*.

Despite these settings being enabled, the screen goes blank after a few minutes even when plugged in. There is another option, *Always On Display* which forces the screen to stay on at all times, even when not plugged-in, but that drains the battery very fast, so it is not practical.

Since I use the phone as one would an alarm-clock, I would like it to keep showing its lock-screen which shows the current time whenever it is connected via its USB-C port. Is there a workaround to restoring the expected behavior?

Comment: 1) What make/model/OS version of various phones? 2) Is the USB plugged into a PC with `adb` running or directly to a wall outlet power supply?

Comment: Asus Zenfone 8 Flip - Android 11 - USB-C Charger Directly from 120V electric main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out another option influences this behavior in Android 11and that is the `Default USB Configuration`. After selecting a specific USB Configuration (any other than `No Data Transfer`), *Stay Awake*  behaves as it did in earlier Android releases.

@MorrisonChang provided a good hint in his comment because when plugged to a computer, *Stay Awake* did work as intended but not with a standalone charger, unless a `Default USB Configuration` is set.